# How to map the Alt key to remote Ubuntu based on VNC from a Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, vnc

I use a Bluetooth Dell keyboard with my Mac, however, I have to use RealVNC to visit an Ubuntu Linux server remotely. I found that the Alt key has been translated into some Unicode symbols. How I can change keymap to directly send my Alt key to Linux.

The vnc client is realvnc and the server is TightVNC

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties of you connection and change to the tab Expert and then set LeftOptKey to Alt_L, works perfect for me!